# Multi-threaded program not faster than single thread on Mac, but on Linux, unless Clang is used

Tags: c, multithreading, macos, pthreads, clang

I am writing a C program which uses `pthreads` to do some matrix multiplication (C=A*B) and then compute the maximum row sum norm of the result, which is the only part that actually requires synchonisation as the matrix multiply itself is independently distributed. Each thread gets its own slice of the rows of matrix A and then multiplies its rows by B and stores them into the corresponding rows of C. So all threads write to different memory locations while reading from the same, which is not being modified.

Now the issue is that when I compile the program on my MacBook (mid-2012, dual core) with two threads, the threaded version is almost exactly as fast as a version without threads, no matter how large I make the matrices. It would be expected that for small matrix size, the overhead of thread spawning and such would eliminate the speedup, but that is not the problem here.
The weird thing is, if I run the same program on a Red Hat Linux server, the speedup is very visible, while on my computer the serial version is always a tiny bit faster. The server has 16 cores, but I'm only using two threads (otherwise it would be pointless).

Does anyone have any suggestions why the same program shows speedup on the server but not on my MacBook?
Here is some code so you see what I'm doing.

**EDIT:** I tried to compile with clang instead of gcc on the Mac, and – magically – the speedup is there, as you'd expect. Any explanation welcome, why on earth gcc does not manage to distribute threads on different CPU's, but clang does. One would think I'm not the first person to experience this.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "assignment3.h"

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   int n, p = 1;
   printf("Please enter the number of processors.\n > ");
   scanf("%d", &p);
   do {
      printf("Please enter the matrix factor "
            "(matrix size is a multiple of processor number).\n > ");
         scanf("%d", &n);
   } while(n % p);
   /* printf("n and p have values %d and %d\n", n, p); */

   // make matrices
   double **A, **B, **C;
   A = malloc(n*sizeof(double *));
   B = malloc(n*sizeof(double *));
   C = malloc(n*sizeof(double *));
   if (A == NULL || B == NULL || C == NULL) {
      return 1;
   }
   A[0] = malloc(n*n*sizeof(double));
   B[0] = malloc(n*n*sizeof(double));
   C[0] = calloc(n*n, sizeof(double));
   int i;
   for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      A[i] = A[0] + i*n;
      B[i] = B[0] + i*n;
      C[i] = C[0] + i*n;
   }

   // Fill with random values between 0 and 1
   fillMatrix(n, A);
   fillMatrix(n, B);

   pthread_t *workers = malloc(p * sizeof(pthread_t));
   thread_data_t *data = malloc(p * sizeof(thread_data_t));
   pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
   double global_norm;
   void **status = malloc(sizeof(void *)); // leaving out malloc is fine on osx, not on linux

   for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
      data[i].n = n;
      data[i].p = p;
      data[i].my_row = i * n/p;
      data[i].A = A;
      data[i].B = B;
      data[i].C = C;
      data[i].mutex = &mutex;
      data[i].global_norm = &global_norm;
   }


   struct timeval tv1, tv2;
   struct timezone tz;

   gettimeofday(&tv1, &tz);
   for (i = 0; i < p; i++) // multiply uses ATLAS to multiply this thread's portion of the matrices
      pthread_create(&workers[i], NULL, multiply, &data[i]);

   for (i = 0; i < p; i++) pthread_join(workers[i], status);
   gettimeofday(&tv2, &tz);
   double elapsed = (double) (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec) + (double)
      (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) * 1.e-6;

   // do non-parallel computation
   struct timeval tv3, tv4;
   struct timezone tz2;
   gettimeofday(&tv3, &tz2);
   double global_norm_serial = multiply_serial(A, B, C, n); // plain serial multiply with ATLAS
   gettimeofday(&tv4, &tz2);
   double elapsed_serial = (double) (tv4.tv_sec - tv3.tv_sec) + (double)
      (tv4.tv_usec - tv3.tv_usec) * 1.e-6;

   printf("Time elapsed for parallel execution: %lf seconds.\n", elapsed);
   printf("Time elapsed for serial execution: %lf seconds.\n", elapsed_serial);



   /* puts("Matrix A:"); */
   /* printMatrix(n, A); */
   /* puts("Matrix B:"); */
   /* printMatrix(n, B); */
   /* puts("Matrix C:"); */
   /* printMatrix(n, C); */
   printf("The maximum row sum norm is %lf.\n", global_norm);
   printf("The maximum (serial) row sum norm is %lf.\n", global_norm_serial);

   free(A[0]);
   free(B[0]);
   free(C[0]);
   free(A);
   free(B);
   free(C);
   free(workers);
   free(data);
   pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
   return 0;
}
```

**EDIT2:**
I don't know how this could help, but this is what the `multiply` procedure does:

```
void *multiply(void *arg){
   thread_data_t *data = arg;
   int n = data->n, 
       p = data->p, 
       my_row = (*data).my_row;
   cblas_dgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, n/p, n, n, 1.0,
         (data->A)[my_row], n, (data->B)[0], n, 0.0, (data->C)[my_row], n);

   pthread_mutex_lock(data->mutex);
   double max = findMax(data->C + my_row, n, n/p, data->my_row);
   if (*(data->global_norm) < max) 
      *(data->global_norm) = max;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(data->mutex);

   pthread_exit(NULL);
   return NULL;
}
```

The type `thread_data_t` has these members:

```
typedef struct {
   int n, p, my_row;
   double **A;
   double **B;
   double **C;
   double *global_norm;
   pthread_mutex_t *mutex;
} thread_data_t;
```

Comment: It might be helpful to see the actual thread function `multiply()`.

Comment: You don't need to allocate memory for the `status` (which you have forgotten to `free`) either declare a `void* status;` variable and call `pthread_join(workers[i], &status)` or simply do `pthread_join(workers[i], NULL)`

Comment: Fair enough. I did that because I was getting a segfault on linux (not mac though), when leaving `status` as a pointer-to-pointer uninitialized, but it works like you propose, by declaring only a simple pointer and using `&`on it.

Comment: Your performance could be limited by memory bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so for what it's worth, my instructor and I seem to have discovered what the issue is. I did not provide any information on how I compile and link my program, so nobody could possibly have guessed it really. At least not without a strike of genius.

The compiling for the case that did not show any speedup was done like this:

```
gcc-mp-4.7 $(CFILES) $(MANUALPROG) -lcblas -latlas -Wall -o assignment3
```

where `CFILES` are my source files and `MANUALPROG` is just a switch between two different versions.

Well, I was using the gcc 4.7 installed by MacPorts. I did not specifically include the location of `libblas.a` as I – from the fact that there's no errors – assumed it would be in the standard search path of this compiler. I thought this search path included the MacPorts directory `/opt/local/lib`, wherein `libblas.a` and `libatlas.a` reside. So I assumed gcc would link against these libraries. Well, no.

If instead of the above, I use

```
gcc-mp-4.7 -L/opt/local/lib $(CFILES) $(MANUALPROG) -lcblas -latlas -Wall -o assignment3
```

Then the speedup was visible. Therefore, the issue was **not tied to clang or a specific compiler**, and the same happened with Apple's gcc. It was only a question of which libraries were used.

So, since OS X does not have the `ldd` tool, I used `otool -L` on my executable and found out that in the first case, the output is this

```
$> otool -L assignment3
assignment3:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libgcc/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

Contrarily, for the second case, it was this

```
$> otool -L assignment3
assignment3:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
    /opt/local/lib/libgcc/libgcc_s.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
```

Turns out that if I don't explicitly specify a path where the library is, the compiler dynamically links to the BLAS version which Apple provides. By explicitly including the MacPorts version, this is prevented.

Now, coming back to *why* one version is faster: My instructor remarked that there's different implementations of BLAS/ATLAS, which can be multithreaded themselves, or not. Now it looks like *Apple's version is multithreaded and MacPorts' is not*. Why? Because assuming the BLAS routine I'm calling is threaded itself, then it does not matter if I create threads myself and then call the routine in each one or if I put in the whole matrix in a single call to the routine – it will be split up into threads anyway. Surely, me making my own threads eats up some more time, which accounts for the fact that the "parallel" execution time was always just a little longer.

If, on the other hand, the BLAS routine is *not threaded*, then we should see some difference when making our own threads – and this is what happens. Linking statically to the MacPorts library means having serial BLAS calls in the program. So when I divide those into threads, we should see the speedup – and we do. 
As a matter of fact, the execution time when dynamically linking against Apple's framework is approximately the same (slightly less) like the execution time for the version statically linking to the MacPorts library and using my own threads.

I have no way of ascertaining whether one or the other BLAS implementation is threaded or not, but the explanation fits the data.

Answer (score -2):

I think the most likely reason is that you can't be sure the 2 threads will run on different processors. You'd need to look into how the OS decides to allocate processor resources.

Comment: Perhaps, but I just assumed that since there are two processors, they will also be used. I now compiled with Clang instead of gcc on my Mac, and suddenly, there _is_ the speedup one would expect. Why could this be the case?

Comment: Is my answer wrong? It would help if whoever did the minus 1 would say what is wrong with it. I'm here to learn as well as to answer.

Comment: While I did not give the downvote, I _do_ think your answer is overly simplistic, because modern OSes don't put your threads on the same core when you have more than one I think. That would be just silly. But I also have no profound knowledge of the topic.

Comment: @Spalteer There is no basis for your claim that it's the "most likely reason". I concede it's theoretically possible, but it seems absurdly improbable. If there's one thing that's likely to fully understand how to get performance out of the CPU, it's the scheduler.